# Simple Kinematics question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

So this is a pretty simple kinematics question I was working on but I completely skipped over a derivation.

[image]

Here's what I did to solve for the first part:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is anyway to solve for the second part that differs from the book. My brain just kind of gave out. I did the derivation that the solution gives after realizing I had forgotten the equation they use. Just curious to see how other's would go about solving this if they had not known the velocity equation between two points.

Here's the solution:
[image]

Comment: Another way to solve? Sure. Use work-energy theorem.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can split the second part into two subquestions: after which time does the rocket hit the ground, and what is its velocity at that moment?

The time can be derived from $s_a + v_at - \frac{1}{2}at^2=0$. It should equal zero in this case as you want to determine the time it takes for the rocket to reach zero height. Entering the values presented in the question gives either t=-0.5159 and t=15.8064. We pick the positive solution for obvious reasons.

Next, we calculate the velocity after 15.8064s, by solving $v=v_a - at$, where $v_a$ is the initial velocity. This gives $v=-80.1$, now with a minus sign as the velocity is in the opposite direction.

**Edit:**
In order to have better agreement with the homework-answering policy as in the link by Kyle Kanos, I add the following.

The two solutions presented (by me and by the textbook) take different approaches for the problem. My solution more or less follows a kinematical perspective: how does the rocket proceed in time?

The textbook solution uses energy conservation: at each moment during the rocket's trajectory, total energy (kinetic + potential) should be constant. With the values given in the exercise, it is possible to calculate the initial energy: $E_{kin}=\frac{1}{2}mv_A^2$, $E_{pot}=mgs_A$. Note that you don't know the mass of the rocket, but it is not needed in the end.
For the situation at the ground, $E_{pot}=0$ as the height is zero. Energy conservation gives: $\frac{1}{2}mv_A^2 + mgs_A = \frac{1}{2}mv_C^2$. Dividing by the mass and rearranging gives the textbook solution: $v_C^2 = v_A^2 + 2gs_A$.